# Integer condition and perfect square relation

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Suppose $a,b,c,d$ are integers such that $a+b+c+d$=0. Prove that $2a^4+2b^4+2c^4+2d^4+8abcd$ is a perfect square. I eliminated $a,b,c,d$, then the steps went lengthy and I could not concretise

Comment: Maybe you can use the symmetric polynomials $s_n$: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial

Answer (score 1):

If you replace $d=-a-b-c$, then wolfram alpha says you can write it like this:
$2a^4+2b^4+2c^4+2d^4+8abcd=4 (a^2+a b+a c+b^2+b c+c^2)^2$. I don't think there is an efficient way to prove it's a square otherwise.